# SQL syntax to select an entire table with values replaced with values in other tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite DB with one table that holds IDs for several strings, like so:

```
id    sym_const
1     play
2     go
3     fill
4     say
```

The DB also has several tables other with several columns of integer data, with the integers being IDs corresponding to strings in the above table:

```
attr    val_const
1       3
4       2
```

I need to do a query to grab the rows from the second table, but replacing the integers with their corresponding strings from the first table, like so:

```
attr    val_const
play    fill
say     go
```

How would I do this? FYI, this is for exploring the semantic memory database of a [Soar](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/soar/home) application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Table Names:

```
SELECT  attr        = m1.sym_const,
        val_const   = m2.sym_const
  FROM  SecondTable s
        JOIN MainTable m1 on m1.id = s.attr
        JOIN MainTable m2 on m2.id = s.val_const
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN`. Look up SQL syntax documentation if you're not sure what that means.